# How to get 1MB flashable bios from the 6MB bios package provided by HP?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, bios

My bios chip is fried. I read that a new chip can be programmed via a Raspberry Pi.

The particular chip I had was 25qh16, (2MB).

So, I went ahead and download the .exe Bios package from HP. Unzipped it, and extracted the .bin file. However, the .bin file is of 5.7 MB, but the SOIC is only 2MB.

If I try to flash it, it won't work.

How do I flash an empty chip with the bios?